# How can I get a vector type in C#?

Tags: c#, vector, directx

I want to use Vectors in a C# application I'm writing, sepcifically a Vector3.

What's the best way for me to get a Vector type without writing my own?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I used one in a POC that I found on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/VectorType.aspx). It's not ideal, but it worked for our situation. At the time, however, it did not have a method to reflect a Vector3 about a given normal, but that may have changed since then.

If you don't mind using DirectX (some stay away from it for whatever reason), then there is a [Vector3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsmobile.directx.vector3.aspx) type in that library as well.

Answer (score 8):

Well, there's a struct called `Microsoft.DirectX.Vector3` if that's what you're looking for. You need to reference `Microsoft.DirectX.dll` to use it.

Answer (score 5):

For completeness, there is also one in XNA: Microsoft.XNA.Framework.Vector3.

Sounds like something in dire need of consolidation.

Answer (score 3):

In WPF you have:

[System.Windows.Media.Media3D.Vector3D](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.media3d.vector3d.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use the vector classes in SlimDX:  http://code.google.com/p/slimdx/

You could also pull out the vector/math classes from an open source XNA port like XNATouch: http://xnatouch.codeplex.com/